# jquery run through tables and only do something if 2x TDs

Tags: jquery, expand

I am in a special "problem" here. Ti accommodate a request from a client I need to do the following. Run through all tables on a page. For each table check if it has exactly 2 TD's. If it does then I need to make a "read more" implementation.

I have used this on another page where I know the exact div's I want to collapse and expand.

```
$(".more-block").each(function(){
    if ($(this).height() > adjustheight){
        id = this.id;
        id = id.split("_");
        $("#expand"+id[1]).toggle(function() {
                id = this.id;
                $(".more-block"+id).css('height', 'auto').css('overflow', 'visible');
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 'slow');
                $("#"+id).attr('src',path+'/images/expand2.png');
                $(".frontpage_box").css('height', '');
            }, function() {
                id = this.id;
                $("#"+id).attr('src',path+'/images/expand.png');
                $(".more-block"+id).animate({height: adjustheight}, "slow", function(){
                    $(".more-block"+id).css('height', adjustheight).css('overflow', 'hidden');
                });         
        });
    };
});

$(".more-block").css('height', adjustheight).css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

Any ideas?
When I run through the TD's I could just add the classes "more-less" and "more-lessexpand1" (number is increment). Is this possible? I am not sure how to run the tables and only do this if two TD's is found and only do this last bit on the second TD.

Oh and by the way... its important its only the second TD that collapses and expands. The left one is not allowed to. I might be able to solve this last bit if someone could help me find the TD's of interest.

Please help

Comment: What part are you stuck with? Finding `table` elements with exactly two `td` elements? The `read more` implementation..?

Comment: Firstly, set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), secondly, are you sure you should be doing this kind of work for clients ?

Comment: I am stuck in the finding the TD's issue. @nnnnnn seems to have posted a solution that I am gonna try out. And adeneo - auch... your always welcome to contribute with another solutions that would be more than helpful... no need for that other part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *" I might be able to solve this last bit if someone could help me find the TD's of interest."*

Something like this will find the table(s) of interest, assuming you don't have nested tables:

```
$("table").each(function() {
   var $tds = $(this).find("td");
   if ($tds.length != 2)
       return;
   // this is a table with exactly two cells, so do something
   // $tds.eq(0) will reference first td;
   // $tds.eq(1) will reference second td;
   // So to add the classes to the second cell...
   $tds.eq(1).addClass("more-less more-lessexpand1");
});
```

Comment: Thanks I am going to give it a go.

Comment: You're welcome. And let me say congratulations on your "give it a go" attitude. A lot of people post questions to SO expecting others to implement entire solutions for them, so it's really nice to see somebody asking for hints and guidance with the intention of experimenting and doing the rest themselves. Playing around and trying things out is what programming is all about.

Comment: Thanks m8 :) its all working perfectly now and I have all the rest figured out.

Comment: I have a quick follow-up question. If I have a table inside a table this fails. It then counts more TD's. Is there anyway to ignore tables in tables or at least count the new table for it self?

Comment: You could try `$(this).children("tr").children("td")` instead of `$(this).find("td")`, because `.find()` (depending on the selector) returns all descendants, but `.children()` only returns immediate children. (The reason I used `.find()` in the first place is that I'm not quite sure how `tbody` fits into things here. You _might_ need to change the outer selector to `table > tbody`).

Comment: Fantastic m8 :) Looking forward to trying this out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('table').filter(function(
    return $('td', this).length==2;
)).find('td').last().addClass('more-less more-lessexpand1');
```

Comment: Adeneo I haven't tried your solution yet... nnnnnn's solution works. Is there a big difference between your answers? Anything I should be aware of?

Comment: I don't think this will quite work. The `.filter()` part will find all of the table elements on the page that have exactly two cells, so far so good, but then the `.find('td').last().addClass(...)` will only apply to the last cell of the last table, not to the last cell of every two-cell table.

Comment: @nnnnnn - yep, I noticed it when I posted it, but completely forgot to edit it, should be wrapped in a $.each() function to work properly.